# GLib parsing integer from string

Tags: parsing, integer, glib

I'm trying to parse value from string in C for GLib application.
The result is well-compiled freezing app with no error/warning.

I post the function used to be launched for specific thread. The function is a **stub** only.

```
int i;
gchar *buffer="";





void *mainthreadfunc(){

  buffer = g_strdup ("25");
  i = atoi((char *)buffer);
  for(;i<10;i++){
    g_print("The i is: %d\n", i);
    g_usleep (1000000);
  }

}
```

Comment: There isn't really anything wrong with the code you posted (the loop never executes because `25 > 10`, but changing the 10 to 100 fixes that, and you leak buffer, and `=""` probably isn't a great idea).  You should consider posting a SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Also just use g_ascii_strtoull().

Comment: They don't do the same thing (which is why `g_ascii_strtoull` exists).